# Choose between 32 and 64 bit for an NSIS installer?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, nsis

I have found some similar questions but I'm not totally sure that they answer my question. I am needing to include Java within my installer, however, we will not know whether the client is using 32 or 64 bit and we do not want to make the assumption. We have considered just using the 32 bit JRE since it will also work on 64 bit systems and it will also not require packaging more than one JRE. We also will not know if the client has internet connectivity to have it connect and choose for the client. Is there an easy way to decide between these two in NSIS? Should I just use the 32 bit JRE and not worry about it?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Once a 32x executable runs, it's difficult to determine if you're running on x64 system. Typically, we generate both a x32 and x64 package and let the user decide

Comment: This totally depends on your application. If you want/must support small heaps and if it actually works. For Desktop Applications this might be required, on a (Windows) Server there is no recent version with only 32bit support anyway. You can also offer it to select an existing VM.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Where did you get the idea that it is difficult, Windows has an official API function to determine this...

Comment: @Anders Do you have link for it, every time I've gone looking the suggestion has been that anything is a hack or unreliable under certain conditions

Comment: @MadProgrammer: IsWow64Process()

Comment: @Anders Thanks, I'll do some research

Comment: @Anders From what I've read, `IsWow64Process` only makes sense if your a x32 bit process, this is probably why I suggest making the determination is difficult, at least from a Java point of view, because you could be running within a x64 bit process

Comment: @MadProgrammer: But you usually know if your pointer size is 32 or 64 bit. I'm sure java has a way of telling you. If not you can call LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32") and look at the raw bytes in the PE header, or call GetNativeSystemInfo() and there are probably other ways to tell as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS has a header file with some helper macros for 64-bit stuff:

```
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
!if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" >= 8
  DetailPrint "64-bit installer"
!else
  ${If} ${RunningX64}
    DetailPrint "32-bit installer on a 64-bit OS"
  ${Else}
    DetailPrint "32-bit installer on a 32-bit OS"
  ${EndIf}
!endif
SectionEnd
```

Comment: So, if it is a 32x executable, it can detect this?

Comment: I was just wondering if it would work for both a x32 and x64 bit executable the same way is all ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Well no, it does not work the same way. We know that 64-bit programs cannot run on 32-bit versions of Windows so we can just hardcode the result at compile-time for the 64-bit program...